# Difference between 'level.tick()' and 'Level.tick(level)'

Tags: java

I'm a Java devloper in my spare time and i just was wondering what would be the difference between

```
level.tick()
```

and

```
Level.tick(level)
```

('Level' being the name of the class and 'level' being an object of that class)

I know that since java works by referencing objects, that calling the static function from the class passing the level as parameters would surely have the same effect as 'level.tick()'

(Please note this is not for a project I'm working on, I just thought I'd ask)
)

Comment: can you show us the `Level` class? We can only guess answers without knowing how `tick()` and `tick(Level l)` are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can implement the same functionality. Most commonly you use the first *instance method* declaration. However, if level can be `null`, then you would need to add a checking before that call. The second *static method* declaration can include this checking and reduce the boilerplate you have to write.

```
public class Level {
  public void tick();
  public static void tick(Level level);
}

level.tick(); // Safe to call if level can't be null
Level.tick(level); // Safe to call in any case
```

Designing the application so that variable values are never or only in exceptional cases are `null` can save you from a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1):

The first method will call the non static function of Level class which is accepting no arguments.
The second method will call the static function of Level class which is expecting an argument of type Level.

Comment: the first syntax could also call a static function with no arguments.

Comment: You cannot have a static method with same signature

Comment: Right, but is does not have the same signature, `tick()` vs. `tick(Level)`

Comment: Yea..but in that case, how the first syntax call a static function with no arguments?

Comment: It has the same effect as `Level.tick()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,

> I know that since java works by referencing objects, that calling the static function from the class passing the level as parameters would surely have the same effect as 'level.tick()'

```
Level.tick(level)
```

does NOT automatically translate to

```
level.tick()
```

This would only work if you had a static function which had the 2nd form as the body.